# Are there any primary sources on the letter Hulagu wrote to Qutuz?

Tags: mongol-empire

I was wondering if there are any primary sources on the letter that the Mongol Khan [Hulagu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulagu_Khan) wrote to the Mamluk Sultan [Qutuz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qutuz) (from Wikipedia: "Hulagu intended to continue southward through Palestine towards Cairo to fight the Mamluks. He sent a threatening letter to the Mamluk Sultan Qutuz in Cairo. He demanded that Qutuz open Cairo or it would be destroyed like Baghdad.") Everywhere I looked they didn't give a concrete source, is there maybe the letter preserved or maybe a transcript written during that time? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? What did you find? Please help us to help you. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [Help Centre](https://history.stackexchange.com/help) and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: Please cite all nouns. Who is Hulagu? Who is Qutuz? When?   Please give us more information to start research.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.quora.com/Where-can-I-find-the-translated-letter-that-Hulagu-Khan-wrote-to-the-caliph-of-Baghdad

> I believe that this is [John Woods'](https://history.uchicago.edu/directory/john-e-woods) translation of Rashid al-Din Fazlallah 'Conquest of Bagdad'. (quoted at [Conquest of Baghdad (1258) by Rashid al-Din Fazlallah (d. 1318)](https://ballandalus.wordpress.com/2014/08/01/conquest-of-baghdad-1258-by-rashid-al-din-fazlallah-d-1318/)).
>
> It should be noted that  [Rashid-al-Din Hamadani](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashid-al-Din_Hamadani) was a Jewish Muslim working for the Ilkhanids and also their Grand vizier  before he was executed. So it is a moot point as to whether he ever actually saw the original letter, of which no copies exist, made it up entirely, 'improved' the original or a copy,  or embroidered tales that he had heard for political impact.
>
> You can read the original [here](http://images.is.ed.ac.uk/luna/servlet/detail/UoEsha%7E4%7E4%7E64392%7E103065;jsessionid=F61E93951C740C1EAF023EFCDF4BA137?cic=UoEsha%7E4%7E4&mi=1&qvq=q%3A9999999%3Bsort%3AWork_Creator_Details%2CWork_Shelfmark%2CWork_Source_Page_No%2CWork_Title%3Blc%3AUoEsha%7E4%7E4&sort=Work_Creator_Details%2CWork_Shelfmark%2CWork_Source_Page_No%2CWork_Title&trs=2), and it is worth taking just a few minutes as it is a beautiful example of medieval illustrated calligraphy.

Comment: does anyone have a working link to Conquest of Baghdad (1258) by Rashid al-Din Fazlallah (d. 1318).